# compilation error in example midlet from Java ME 3.0

Tags: java, java-me, midp, midlet, java-micro-editon-sdk3.0

There are many example in j2me sdk 3.0 (http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javame/javamobile/download/overview/index.html)

I'm trying to build example to learn more about MIDlet 2d graphics.

```
  AGUISwingSet2 error: package javax.swing does not exist

  BdjGunBunny error: package java.awt does not exist
```

How to build it or include those package?

Comment: Can you please provide correct and working URL.

Comment: What is this url **http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/ja...iew/index.html**? try post properly.

Comment: Sorry, the link was tracked. Correct link http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javame/javamobile/download/overview/index.html But the link is just to mention about those example comes together in the same SDK package. I think it will be better if I give the a link for those problematic example. Here is the link where I get compilation error. https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B08T2-rP3WGAYzY0MzhiY2ItYzI0My00ZTE5LWJhYWEtNTc4MzU3ZmI3MzVi

Answer (score 1):

> I'm trying to build example to learn more about MIDlet 2d graphics.
>
> > ```
> >   AGUISwingSet2 error: package javax.swing does not exist
> >
> >   BdjGunBunny error: package java.awt does not exist
> > ```

Your mistake is expecting the [AGUI](http://developers.sun.com/mobility/midp/articles/guiapis/#5) examples to work with MIDlets based on [MIDP (JSR 118) API](http://docs.oracle.com/javame/config/cldc/ref-impl/midp2.0/jsr118/index.html). This ain't possible.

- If you want to *learn more about MIDlet 2d graphics* then find other examples.
- If you want to study examples *AGUISwingSet2* and *BdjGunBunny* then recondigure SDK platform for CDC stack - as [described in their documentation here](http://docs.oracle.com/javame/dev-tools/jme-sdk-3.0.5/developer-guide/platforms.htm)

Answer (score 0):

Try to add those package (if you are using netbeans IDE). right click on project name>properties>build>libraries&Resource> Add Library. Hope it will solve your problem.

Comment: Those examples are for CDC not for CLDC. I thought it is may be for CLDC. It is ok if I anybody want to make CDC app using those library.